# php script exited after run http_response_code

Tags: php, apache

I got my server provisioned by other guy with php-fpm and apache httpd 2.4.

when I put on the following page.

```
<?php
$result = http_response_code(200);
var_dump($result);
phpinfo();
```

it showed on the page the int(200) and php info page.

however, when I change 200 to 404, it shows me the default 404 page configured in apache instead of executing the dumped content and php info page.

That means the script exit after executing `http_response_code(404);` with out executing the left code.

At first I think it was related with php-fpm but when I tried to setup a docker container with php-fpm and apache, it continue to execute the code  after `http_response_code(404);`.

Now I got confused wondering if it's related with my apache configuration or php setting.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's exiting after that line? Try writing to a file or something that doesn't depend on visibly seeing the data in the response

Comment: @Phil you are right.  I tried to  write to file after the http_response_code and it works. So the problem should be my apache setting. Thank you for your hint.

Comment: Apache is just handling the 404 response for you as directed through the `ErrorDocument` configuration

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found out the reason.

The config `ProxyErrorOverride on` makes my error status be handled by apache instead of php-fpm.

So I commented out and restart. Everything is ok now.